Для чего нужна функция abs?
Например, что значит это выражение?
X= abs(int(s))

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Про abs

Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Что делать с ответами на вопрос?


Например, что значит это выражение? X= abs(int(s))

Это значит, что на значение переменной s применится сначала функция int() и на результат еще функция abs().


Результатом функции int() будет — или, как принято говорить, функция int() возвращает — целое число. (Но только тогда, когда это возможно сделать. Например int('барабан') не имеет смысла, и вместо результата вы получите сообщение об ошибке.)

Результатом функции abs(), примененной на целое число, будет — так как и в математике — абсолютная величина этого числа.



Например, значение переменной s вы получили в результате команды
s = input('Введите какое-нибудь целое число: ')

когда пользователь на вызов

Введите какое-нибудь целое число: |   


нажал на клавиатуре постепенно клавиши -127Enter.
В переменной s не будет число -127, а строка '-127', потому что функция input() всегда возвращает строку из всех символов введенных до окончания клавишем Enter.
Ваше выражение
X = abs(int(s))


сначала сделает из этой строки '-127' целое число -127 (применилась функция int())
и затем из числа -127 сделает абсолютную величину, т.е. число 127
(на результат функции int() применилась функция abs()).


В итоге вы в переменной X получите значение 127.

Функция abs() возвращает модуль числа. Т. е. abs(-5) вернет 5, а abs(9) вернет 9.

Это не так просто. Например, abs(5-12j) вернет 13, и даже для некоторых более сложных объектов может применяться эта функция.
